# Transitioning Two Sets of Elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a stacked bar graph. I want to add some nice transitions to my graph, but I am getting an error. Where if I try to transition both rectangles, only the blue rectangles transition in and appear.
[image]

```
let rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(heartDiseaseByAge);
      let displayHealth = async () => {
        //healthy rects
        rects
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", (width - spacing * 2) / xLabelCount - 15)
          .attr("height", (d) => {
            console.log(d.ageRange + " " + d.noDiseaseCountPercent);
            return yScale(d.noDiseaseCountPercent);
          })
          .attr("x", (d, i) => {
            return i * (width / xLabelCount) + spacing;
          })
          .attr("y", (d) => height - yScale(d.noDiseaseCountPercent) - spacing)
          .attr("fill", "#0091DA")
          .on("mouseover", (event, d, i) => {
            onMouseOver(event, d, i);
          })
          .on("mouseout", (e) => {
            onMouseOut(e);
          })
          .on("mousemove", (e) => {
            onMouseMove(e);
          });
      };

      //unhealthy rects
      let displayUnhealthy = async () => {
        rects
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("width", (width - spacing * 2) / xLabelCount - 15)
          .attr("height", (d) => {
            return yScale(d.hasDiseaseCountPercent);
          })
          .attr("x", (d, i) => {
            return i * (width / xLabelCount) + spacing;
          })
          .attr("y", (d) => {
            return (
              height -
              yScale(d.hasDiseaseCountPercent) -
              yScale(d.noDiseaseCountPercent) -
              spacing
            );
          })
          .attr("fill", "#E52E2E")
          .on("mouseover", (event, d, i) => {
            onMouseOver(event, d, i);
          })
          .on("mouseout", (e) => {
            onMouseMove(e);
          })
          .on("mousemove", (e) => {
            onMouseMove(e);
          });
      };

      await displayHealth();
      await displayUnhealthy();
```

When I call:

```
rects
              .enter()
              .append("rect")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
              .attr("width", (width - spacing * 2) / xLabelCount - 15)
              .attr("height", (d) => {
                return yScale(d.hasDiseaseCountPercent);
              })
              .attr("x", (d, i) => {
                return i * (width / xLabelCount) + spacing;
              })
              .attr("y", (d) => {
                return (
                  height -
                  yScale(d.hasDiseaseCountPercent) -
                  yScale(d.noDiseaseCountPercent) -
                  spacing
                );
              })
              .attr("fill", "#E52E2E")
              .on("mouseover", (event, d, i) => {
                onMouseOver(event, d, i);
              })
              .on("mouseout", (e) => {
                onMouseMove(e);
              })
              .on("mousemove", (e) => {
                onMouseMove(e);
              });
```

Only the blue bars transition in and appear, but the red bars never appear, even when I call transition on the red rects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rects` selection has just one rectangle for data point in the `heartDiseaseByAge` array, regardless the fact that you have two or even more "enter" selection for those rectangles.

A very simple solution is creating *two* selections, one for each category:

```
let rectsHealthy = svg.selectAll("rect").data(heartDiseaseByAge);
let rectsUnhealthy = svg.selectAll("rect").data(heartDiseaseByAge);
```

Even though their dataset is the same, what they represent is clearly different. Then, you can manipulate each selection independently.

Comment: PS: It seems to me (I didn't see the whole code) that those `async... await` you have are unnecessary.